# understanding IIFE's, why is function expression being pushed as opposed to pushing the executed value

Tags: javascript, iife

In the following function why does arr contain a function and not the value of x? and in the second function why are the elements of the array undefined

```js
function makeFunctionArray3() {
    console.log('three')
    const arr = []

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr.push(
            (function(x) {
                return (function() {
                    console.log(x)
                })
            })(i)
        )
    }

    return arr
}

functionArr = makeFunctionArray3()

functionArr[3]()
console.log(functionArr)


function makeFunctionArray4() {
    console.log('four')
    const arr = []

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr.push(
            (function(x) {
                return console.log(x)               
            })(i)
        )
    }

    return arr
}

functionArr = makeFunctionArray4()


console.log(functionArr)
```

Comment: You are asking why it is not an array of values?? Because it returns a function in the loop, not executing the function.

Comment: Well that `makeFunctionArray3()` functions builds an array, and each element of the array contains the result of invoking an IIFE. That IIFE returns a function when it's invoked, so that's what the resulting array contains.

Comment: if I return console.log(x) how come the elements of the array are undefined?

Comment: The result of calling `console.log()` is `undefined`.

Comment: `console.log(x);` returns `undefined`. If you want to `return x;` then just `return x;`. If you want to log it and return it, then do that: `console.log(x); return x;`

Comment: Because `(function() {
                    console.log(x)
                })` - the return value of the IIFE - is a function.